# Has any language ever supported a conditional assignment target?

Tags: programming-languages, theory, conditions

I've never seen a programming language with conditional assignment targets, eg.:

```
// If (x == y), then var1 will be set to 1, else var2 will be set to 1
((x == y) ? var1 : var2) = 1
```

The target of the assignment is determined conditionally at run-time, in this case based on whether x == y.

It seems like it could be a handy syntax.

Anyone know of any programming language which supports this?

Or is there a theoretical reason it can't be done effectively?

Comment: Yes, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082655/conditional-operator-differences-between-c-and-c

Comment: Does it break the compositionality of the language. since the left side of the assignment has to represent a variable reference in this context, while it normally returns a value in other contexts? Ie. the expression changes meaning not based on what it's composed of but what is surrounding it...

Comment: Ahhhh good point Kilian.

It seems like a bit of a hack in C++ though using simulated reference. Can anyone think of a language which actually implements it natively?

Comment: It's not a reference, it's an *lvalue*. This is a fundamental concept in C++ around which the language is built, so no, this is not a weird exception and it doesn't "break" anything.

Comment: @BrendanHill: It's no more a "hack" than `*ptr = val`

Comment: Far from an answer to this question, but I found in C++ when facing a need similar to this is a `swap_if` function. `swap_if(cond, x, y);`. Then I can assume `y` meets the condition and `x` doesn't, e.g., in the subsequent code. It's for a select use case and may not meet yours, but I've found it handy quite often, and there are some fairly efficient ways to implement this `swap_if` function. This is typically when I want to do multiple things though with the variable between these pairs that meets or doesn't meet the condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't really a theory question, but a practical one.

C++ supports what you're asking about:

> `[C++14: 5.16/4]:` If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value category *[..]*

For example:

```c++
#include <iostream>

int x = 3, y = 4;

void foo(const bool b)
{
    (b ? x : y) = 6;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';   // 3 4
    foo(true);
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';   // 6 4
    foo(false);
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << '\n';   // 6 6
}
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90a13bb5042c73ae))

(This is basically the same as `*ptr = val`, since dereferencing produces an lvalue.)

It's worth noting that C *doesn't* support it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int x = 3, y = 4;

void foo(const bool b)
{
    (b ? x : y) = 6;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);   // 3 4
    foo(true);
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);   // 6 4
    foo(false);
    printf("%d %d\n", x, y);   // 6 6
}

// main.c: In function 'foo':
// main.c:8:17: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
//      (b ? x : y) = 6;
             ^
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8d4ff104db96395))

… though it will allow you to simulate this technique, by applying my early observation regarding pointer dereferences:

```
*(b ? &x : &y) = 6;
```

Comment: Ha, I had no idea, awesome!

Comment: Awesome?  More like aweful :-)

Comment: But you can simulate it in C, if you want: `*(b ? &x : &y) = 6;`

Comment: @Deduplicator: lol yuk

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in Perl.  It is the same as in C++.

```
my $x = 0;
my $y = 0;

1==1 ? $x: $y = 1;

print "x: $x y: $y\n";

$x = 0;
$y = 0;

1==0 ? $x: $y = 1;

print "x: $x y: $y\n";
```

Note: this construct can often lead to confusion.  For example, consider the following code:

```
$condition ? $y = 0 : $x = 1;
```

The person writing this line of code likely thought that `$y` would get set to 0 if `$condition` is true, but actually this evaluates to `$y = 0 = 1`, which gives `$y` a value of 1.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that it's a confusing syntax. Handy though if used appropriately